# How to do login authentication using java rest api and routing in electron js

Tags: javascript, electron

I am beginner working with electron js I have created my first app in electron js and I am trying to do login authentication using java rest API since I am not knowing how to do that I have done completed hard coded authentication.When Login gets success how to do routing to new screen such as dashboard

```js
 const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
            const path = require('path');
            
            const createWindow = () => {
              const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
              });
              mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
            };
        
        app.on('ready', createWindow);
        
        app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
          if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
            app.quit();
          }
        });
        
        app.on('activate', () => {
          if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
          }
        });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Hello World!</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
              </head>
              <body>
                <form>
                  <fieldset>
                   <legend>Login:</legend>
                   <label for="username">UserName</label>
                   <input type="text" id="uname" name="fname"><br><br>
                   <label for="password">Password:</label>
                   <input type="password" id="pwd" name="lname"><br><br>      
                   <input type="submit" value="Login" id="sbtn">
                  </fieldset>
                 </form>
              </body>
              <script>
                document.querySelector('#sbtn').addEventListener('click', () => {
                let userName=document.getElementById("uname").value;
                let pwd=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
                if(userName=="abc" && pwd=="123"){
                  alert("Login sucess");
                }else{
                  alert("Failed to login")
                }
            })
              </script>
            </html>
```